# How can i show that $\det(A)=\det(A^\intercal)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

For all $n$-dimension matrix, how can i show that $\det(A)=\det(A^\intercal)$ by using induction? ($A^\intercal$ is a transpose of $A$)

Comment: What've you tried out?

Comment: How do you define $\det$ ? If you use a definition based on permutations, then it's quite simple.

Comment: Or if you know how elementary row/column operations affect the derivative, and the existence of echelon form, and the determinant of upper-diagonal matrices, it's also simple.

Comment: Yes, by induction (strong induction). For $n=1$, it's clear. Then assume it holds for square matrix of dimension $1,\ldots,n$. You have to prove it holds for $(n+1)\times (n+1)$ matrices. You need a previous result that says that it's the same to expand a determinant, using minors, across any row or any column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ is not invertible, then $A^T$ is also not invertible. So if $det(A) = 0$ then $det(A^T) = 0$ and vice versa. If $A$ is invertible, then $A = E_1\cdot E_2\cdot...E_n$ and $A^T = E_n^T\cdot E_{n-1}^T\cdot ...E_1^T$ with each $E_i$ is an elementary matrix which is obtained by a single row operation on $I_n$, and there are $3$ of types of them. For each of the $3$ types we can verify that $det(E_i) = det(E_i^T)$. So $det(A) = det(E_1)\cdot \det(E_2)\cdot...det(E_n) = det(E_n^T)\cdot det(E_{n-1}^T)\cdot...det(E_1^T) = det(E_n^T\cdot E_{n-1}^T\cdot...E_1^T) = det(A^T)$.